# ios - protocol declared in child class to be followed in base class

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I had two view controller `A` and `B`. A protocol is defined in `B` and followed and implemented `A`.  Instance Of `A` is pushed to navCtrl and then instance of `B` is presented.

Now I made a change `B` is inherited from `A`. Since I wanted to inherit some properties and methods from `A` to `B`.  Now it is giving error `"Cannot find protocol declaration for 'protocolName'"`.

I tried to move protocol declaration from `B.h` to `A.h`, then in `B.h` when I inherit from `A` it says `A` is undefined.

Even `B` is inherited from `A`, both instances are different. Is there a way to do this.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the relation between A and B? Is one a superclass of another or not?

Comment: Yes. A is super class to B.

Comment: Why are you having this model? They are separate view controllers, B doesnt need to inhert from A.

Comment: I have few methods and properties which are common in both. So thought to inherit. Will reduce code.

Comment: That's not what inheritance is supposed to do. If you have methods and properties to both contain, then you create a separate class that both files import (or you can pass it between the two classes) so that you have convenience methods for both.

Comment: Yes. I did that. Just posted question to find if any other option. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: From errors you get it looks like you might be having circular dependencies: `A.h` imports `B.h` and vice versa.